# MongoDB: Sorting records by the sum of other collection

Tags: mongodb, sorting, collections, aggregation-framework

I have two collections `users` and `tasks` and I want to sort the `users` by the sum of tasks that they created in `tasks` collection.

Users collection.

```
users: [
  { _id: ObjectId('1...'), username: 'jack' },
  { _id: ObjectId('2...'), username: 'john' },
  { _id: ObjectId('3...'), username: 'james' }
]
```

Tasks collection.

```
tasks: [
  { _id: ObjectId('...'), userId: '1...', taskName: 'task 1' },
  { _id: ObjectId('...'), userId: '1...', taskName: 'task 2' },
  { _id: ObjectId('...'), userId: '1...', taskName: 'task 3' },
  { _id: ObjectId('...'), userId: '2...', taskName: 'task 1' },
  { _id: ObjectId('...'), userId: '3...', taskName: 'task 1' },
  { _id: ObjectId('...'), userId: '3...', taskName: 'task 2' }
]
```

This is where I came so far.

```
UsersModel.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'tasks',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'userId',
      as: 'tasks'
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      totalTasks: { $sum: '$tasks.userId' }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { totalTasks: -1 }
  }
], (err, res) => {
  if (err) console.log(err)
  console.log(res)
})
```

But I'm getting results like this.

```
[
  { _id: 1..., totalTasks: 0 },
  { _id: 2..., totalTasks: 0 },
  { _id: 3..., totalTasks: 0 }
]
```

But this is what I'm looking for.

```
[
  { _id: 1..., totalTasks: 3 },
  { _id: 3..., totalTasks: 2 },
  { _id: 2..., totalTasks: 1 }
]
```

I'm not sure this is the problem but the type of `users._id` is `ObjectId` and the type of `tasks.userId` is `String`. I'm stuck and need some help.

Comment: Can you convert the `type` of the `tasks.userId` ? What version for mongodb you are on?

Comment: @Ashh You mean code is correct but it won't work unless I convert the type of `tasks.userId` to `ObjectId`? I'm using `v4.0.3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way:

```
  {
    $addFields: {
        temp_id: {$toString: "$_id"}
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'tasks',
      localField: 'temp_id',
      foreignField: 'userId',
      as: 'tasks'
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
         totalTasks: {$size: "$tasks"}
     }
  },
  {
    $sort: { totalTasks: -1 }
  }
```

As long as your scale is not too big this way is fine.

Comment: This only works if both of the `users._id` and `tasks.userId` have the same data type which is `ObjectId`. But my `users._id` is `ObjectId` and `tasks.userId` is `String`. So in this case it doesn't work. I think we need a way to convert the data type in this query.

Comment: if your on mongo 4.0+ you can cast your objectId to string using [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) before the lookup. otherwise you have to do it in code.

Comment: Could you give me an example code if that's not too much? I couldn't figure out to implement `$toString` before `$lookup`.

Comment: i edited my answer, you just add an $addFields stage.

Comment: Thank you so much it's working now. I'm marking as accepted answer.